# How to safely move all my Picasa folders to another drive

Tags: file-management, file-transfer, picasa

My `c:\camera` directory contains about 150Gb of photos and videos, with many years worth of Picasa edits. Generally I haven't used the "save edited photos to disk" function, so what's on disk is currently the original.

I want to move this whole directory to `f:\camera`.

What's the safest, easiest, least disruptive way to do this? I don't want to run any risk of losing all those edits. I don't really care whether what's on disk ends up being the "original" or "edited" version - as long as what's in Picasa is the edited one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all your folders are sub-directories of Camera from within Picassa right click on Camera and select move folder. Select destination and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Doh, of course. Forgot that Picasa has a tree view.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Move Pictures Without Rescanning](https://sites.google.com/site/picasastartersite/users-guide/move-pictures-without-re-scanning) from the PicasaStarter Users Guide:
*(PicasaStarter is a 3rd party tool for multiuser and portable Picasa picture management)*

> 1. If the new database is not already defined, make a new database as a copy of the database for the Pictures to be moved.
> 2. Select the new Database on the destination drive that will be the database for the moved pictures, then click the "Run Picasa"
>      button and you should see all your pictures and albums unchanged so
>      far.
> 3. In the Picasa View Menu go to Folder View and set it to Tree View so you can see where the folders you are moving come from. Any
>      folders that are already on the Portable or Network drive don't need
>      to be moved!
> 4. In the Folders list on the left side of the Picasa Window, find the containing folders for the pictures (for instance "Vacation
>      Pictures" and click on it to be sure it is the right one (It has the
>      pictures and subfolders you have in that folder).
> 5. Right-click on the containing folder name in the folders list.
>      Select "Move Folder" from the drop-down menu.
>
>    ```
>    Picasa Right-Click on a Folder then Click on Move Folder...
>    ```
> 6. Select the location to move the pictures to in the directory list. This should be the folder you are moving the pictures to on the
>      destination drive.
> 7. For instance if you are moving all the pictures in the MY Pictures folder to the Pictures folder on the P: Drive, this would be
>      the folder called P:\Pictures.
>
>    ```
>    Select Location to Move Folder To
>    ```
> 8. This moves the containing folder and all subfolders to the new location. Reminder! If the folder contains other things such as
>      documents they will also be moved! so it might not be the best idea to
>      try to move the My Documents folder!
> 9. Picasa will now be busy for a long while because it has to copy (actually move) all the pictures to the destination drive, and it has
>      to change all the drive letters in the database. Picasa will not
>      rebuild the database or change the face names or albums. After this is
>      done, you have the pictures and database in the new location.
> 10. Repeat the above move folder procedure on the remaining folder(s) to be moved. Make sure any remaining folders you move have
>       not already been moved by right clicking on them and clicking the
>       Locate on Disk option to see where they are on the computer before
>       doing the Move Folder option. DO ALL MOVING IN PICASA, OTHERWISE THE
>       DATABASE WON'T BE UPDATED AND THOSE FOLDERS WILL BE RE-INDEXED!!

Comment: Next time, please use quotes and cite your sources – don't just copy and paste. Thank you.

Comment: Err, to clarify, that's not the Picasa user's guide, that's the PicasaStarter user's guide. PicasaStarter looks to be a 3rd party tool that enhances Picasa with things like the "database" concept described above.